# Should I use a CMS if I can develop it myself?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I'm learning Drupal to save some production time for my websites, but it looks like it's the other way around. Maybe it's because I'm a beginner but I'm seeing that I spend a lot of time trying to make Drupal adjust to what I want, and it's not saving me time at all, maybe it comes with some 'ready to use' stuff but the time required to set it up, 'theme' it, etc it's actually bigger than the time I would need to code it and put it there.

Am I just a CMS noob or are these things overrated?

Comment: You might find this article very useful: http://www.namhost.com/blog/2014-06-11/how-to-choose-right-software-solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Drupal. I think that might be your problem too. Try something like Joomla. As a programmer, its fun to 'reinvent the wheel' to learn how stuff works but in the real world where `time == money` you need to think about what you can get working the best and quickest.

Comment: Why the Drupal bashing? Drupal is far more versatile than Joomla. If you want something easy, sure, go for Joomla. But if you want something that'll allow you to get more stuff done in the long run, use Drupal. You are going to hit way more walls using Joomla.

Comment: @coderama I think Drupal had a recent overhaul if I'm not mistaken. I've heard a lot a terrible things about it so I stayed away from it. Maybe it has changed? My post is over 3 years old so anything could've happened since then.

Comment: Drupal 7 is awful, but give Drupal 6 a bash. We use it on many sites and it works like a charm. Drupal 7 doesn't have all modules that Drupal 6 has, so I haven't bothered learning it yet. I tried building one site in it, but quickly hit a wall. So, I think the confusion comes when people try to use the latest version only to find it very confusing. Drupal 6 is where it's at. :)

Comment: @coderama aha ok, I'll consider it. I'm more of a rails guy these days so I don't dabble in php but if I have a client that requires it, I'll give Drupal another chance.

Answer (score 9):

It will take you 20x the time to create a CMS than configuring a premade one. Unless you have LOTS of time, i would strongly suggest to use a ready made CMS.

Comment: I already have my own CMS that I developed. It's obviously not as good as Drupal but it's very basic and thus much more easier to configure. But I really don't know what's the reality, if i should use one of the big CMS or stick with mine.

Comment: Depends on functionality. If you have all already coded all the things that you need to, maybe you can use yours. However, if you need much more functionality, i'd suggest a ready made one.

Comment: @luqita: Without knowing your needs/requirements no one can say. But in my experience, the main reason for an independent developer to roll his own CMS for a commissioned website is usually ego rather than practicality. Powerful CMSes like Drupal take time to learn, but there are simpler CMSes out there that are still likely better engineered (in terms of extensibility and user interface) than what you've created. Don't discount those based on your experiences with Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

i have been having feelings that honestly all these CMS are straight up corporate hype...alot of "fluff" and unnessecary bulk features, that just crap your site up and make it way more complicated.

yes they make it easy to have a website up in no time, but honestly i think nothing beats having total control of your site and coding yourself if you can do so. this way you are completely independant from any outside software.

Answer (score 0):

For relatively simple websites, you may save yourself a lot of headaches just coding it yourself with HTML and CSS. If you have a lot of dynamic content, or need multiple people working under you to build the site, then a CMS might make more sense.

Comment: I would say for 99% of the businesses out there, a static site would cost them more in the long run than simply setting up the appropriate CMS. Popular CMSes like Wordpress can be set up by the average high school student and be adapted to the needs of most businesses. And there are other equally user-friendly CMSes not based around blogging platforms.

Comment: It only takes 15 minutes to install a CMS, and you can have a professional designer customize the template for you for under $300. The savings you gain from being able to update the content yourself, easily revamp the site, easily migrate the data to a new CMS, extend the site to meet growing needs, etc. easily offset any benefits to deploying a static site. The latter might be easier for an inexperienced web developer, but it's not what's best for the client. Heck you can even use a SaaS CMS platform that a business owner can setup a feature-rich site with in under 5 minutes.

Comment: it depends on many factors. do you want w3c validation? do you want security? I've seen many CMS-based websites with execrable HTML and CSS, I'm talking hundreds of errors, and I've seen many owners of Wordpress sites posting jobs on vWorker.com for cleaning up their hacked sites. cost and speed of deployment aren't always the primary objectives.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good to use CMS to save some production time. But it will be better if you develop some websites by programing. Because if you need add some custom Module or Plug-in, you have to do programming. But CMS can really save your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly doubtful that you can create something as robust and easy to maintain as Drupal in less time than it takes to learn and setup a Drupal install.

But it really depends on your needs and objectives. Is your goal to learn how to program and gain experience developing web applications? Is your goal to develop a better CMS than what is available? If the answer to either of these questions is "yes", then you should build your own CMS regardless of which takes more time.

But if your goal is to create a website (for yourself or for a client), the CMS simply being a means to an end, then in 99% of the cases, it's best to just deploy a CMS or CMS framework. Something you can build in 2-3 months time is never going to compare to something as mature and with as much community support as Drupal. You might be able to code up all of the basic functionality of a CMS, but what about extensibility? or scalability? or maintainability? or user-friendliness? or SEO? or the hundreds of minor features that you never notice when you use a mature CMS, but which add immeasurable convenience and useful functionality that reduce the TCO of a website?

That said, Drupal may not be the best CMS out there for your organization. But just because one CMS doesn't fit your needs doesn't mean that CMSes are overrated. Unless you're running a static site (which unless you're operating a 1-page website, is inexcusable in this day and age), you'll need a CMS of some sort. And if you honestly think you can build a better CMS than Drupal, then you should do it. The internet community will thank you for it.

But more than likely you're just not used to working with a CMS framework. Most sites have nearly identical requirements, so if you're trying to set up a pretty standard basic CRUD site, then you might consider trying a more end-user oriented CMS rather than Drupal. Drupal's complexity comes from its ability to be used as a platform for much more complex applications. That has a cost in terms of ease of configuration and learning curve.

You haven't given us much details about the site you're trying to build or your requirements, but Wordpress can be customized for use as a CMS for many sites. Or you might try something like Traffik, which is more aimed at designers and business owners.

Answer (score 0):

It will take you a lot more time to code a CMS yourself. What drupal version are you using? The latest version Drupal7 is much more user friendly. Till last version of drupal, it was considered to be one of the less user friendly CMS. You can also give a try to wordpress, if it does what you want. It is much easier to install and maintain yourself. Also has lots and lots of great themes.